# Routing custom URLs to Stash templates

Tags: stash, url, routing

I'm using the [Template Routes plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/template-routes) to add custom URLs to my EE site. Out of the box, it's set up to use the default EE templates:

```
$config['template_routes'] = array(
  'blog/:category' => 'site/blog-category',
  'blog/:year/:pagination' => 'site/blog-yearly-archive',
  'blog/:any' => 'site/blog-single',
);
```

but I'm using [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash) so my templates are located in /templates/. I was just wondering if it's possible to route the URLs to these templates instead?

I've tried just using '/templates/site/blog-category' instead but no dice :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to Stash embed templates, using the `stash_file_basepath` config variable? If so, no, Template Routes cannot use those templates. Unless...

You set your stash template path to match the EE template path:

```
$config['tmpl_file_basepath'] = '/path/to/a/folder/';
$config['stash_file_basepath'] = $config['tmpl_file_basepath'].'default_site/site.group/';
```

Then in Template Routes you could call up those templates:

```
$config['template_routes'] = array(
  'blog/:any' => 'site/some_template',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `/site/` bit, so they read `templates/blog-category`, and you should be good to go :).

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo :) - it did read templates/blog-category but that was still looking in the default templates folder I think?

Comment: Oh yeah you wanna look at Rob Sanchez's answer below here. Misunderstood your question.